# Get Category Name for specified Category id in phtml template - Magento2

Tags: magento2

Hello I am new to magento2

I want to get category name from specified category id 
Can anybody help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try following code for getting Category Object in Magento2:

```
$categoryId = 3;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
->load($categoryId);
echo $category->getName();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the Object Manager, try using the answer below this one.

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/38692903/2219831 a @Sanne has suggested

Answer (score 22):

You should never use the `ObjectManager`.

You can put this in the Block, and call the function `getCategoryName()` in the phtml :

```
namespace Company\Module\Block;

class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;    

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCategoryName()
    {
        $categoryId = '43';
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        $categoryName = $category->getName();
        return $categoryName;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jafarpinjar - please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly